# SQLite: Is it possible to have a recursive table expression after an ordinary one within a WITH clause?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to have both an ordinary table expression and a recursive one within the same WITH-statement. As recursive one, depends on the ordinary one I want to have the ordinary table expression first. When I am trying to do this it just doesn't work. Having the recursive table expression first works though.

The following case in SQLFiddle illustrates the problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b5362/3063/0

The following code works fine:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(x) AS ( 
            SELECT datetime('2015-01-01')
                UNION ALL 
        SELECT datetime(x, '+1 MONTHS') FROM dates WHERE x<'2016-01-01' 
    )
,
testi AS (select * from supportContacts
order by id desc)
    SELECT *
    FROM dates;
```

But when I start with the recursive table statement it doesn't work, i.e the following code doesn't work.

```
WITH testi AS (select * from supportContacts
    order by id desc)
,
RECURSIVE dates(x) AS ( 
            SELECT datetime('2015-01-01')
                UNION ALL 
            SELECT datetime(x, '+1 MONTHS') FROM dates WHERE x<'2016-01-01' 
    )
SELECT *
FROM dates;
```

I would be very happy if someone could tell me if it is possible to have the recursive table statement first and in that case how I would do that.

Best Regards // Henri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the word `RECURSIVE`, it must come only once, directly after the `WITH`.

According to the SQL standard, it means that *any* of the following CTEs *might* be recursive (but it's required if any one actually is).

(So the database has to find out by itself whether any particular CTE is recursive or not. For this reason, SQLite (and many other DBs) make this word completely optional.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Following your answer I dropped the word RECURSIVE and the code that didn't work before now worked.